# VB.NET 2008 or higher: Memory violation reading STDIN via winapi

Tags: vb.net, winapi, stdout, stdin, kernel32

I am trying to port a VB6 application to VB.NET.
This is a console application that reads data from STDIN, modifies the data and writes it to STDOUT.

Google is my friend, so I have spend days now on finding a solution.
This search provided me with several versions of the WinApi ReadFile and I tried them all.
Also I have tried several versions of .NET.
However.....In every combination that I have tried, I keep getting memory violation errors.
Errors differ a little bit depending on the ReadFile variant im using, but the are all similar.

See for instance this variant of the error:

```
makeDataFilter < Test.in > Test.Out

Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at makeDataFilter.Filter_IO.ReadFile(Int64 hFile, String& lpBuffer, Int64 nNumberOfBytesToRead, Int64 lpNumberOfBytesRead, String& lpOverlapped)
   at makeDataFilter.Filter_IO.GetData() in C:\Projects\.NET 2019\makeDataFilter\Filter_IO.vb:line 229
   at makeDataFilter.Filter_IO.Main() in C:\Projects\.NET 2019\makeDataFilter\Filter_IO.vb:line 118
```

I use this to get a handle:

```
Public Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
Public Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

' Open en handle to StdIn or StdOut
    Private Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (
        ByVal nStdHandle As Int32
    ) As IntPtr
```

Here is the variant of the ReadFile API call that produces the error above:

```
<DllImport("kernel32")>
Declare Function ReadFile(
    ByVal hFile As Long,
    lpBuffer As String,
    nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long,
    lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long,
    lpOverlapped As String
) As String
```

And here are all the other variations that I found and tried. All give similar errors:

```
' Read from Stdin
'Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32.dll" (
'    ByVal hFile As Long,
'    lpBuffer As Any,
'    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long,
'    lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long,
'    lpOverlapped As Any
') As Long

'Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (
'      ByVal hFile As Long,
'      lpBuffer As String,
'      ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long,
'      lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long,
'      ByVal lpOverlapped As String
') As Long

'Declare Auto Function ReadFile Lib "Kernel32.dll" (
'    ByVal hndRef As Integer,
'    ByVal lpBuffer As StringBuilder,
'    ByVal numberOfBytesToRead As Integer,
'    ByRef numberOfBytesRead As Integer,
'    ByVal flag As Integer
') As Boolean

'Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (
'        ByVal hFile As Integer,
'        ByVal lpBuffer As Integer,
'        ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Integer,
'        lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer,
'        ByVal lpOverlapped As Integer
') As Integer
```

The way I use it in my code is here:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim sBuff As String         
    Dim lBytesRead As Long      
    Dim rc As Long              
                                
    lContentLength = 256        
    sBuff = lContentLength      
    Do
        rc = ReadFile(hStdIn, sBuff, lContentLength, lBytesRead, 0&)
        sFilterData &= Left$(sBuff, lBytesRead)
    Loop While rc = 1
End Sub
```

Can somebody please assist me in finding a working way to read from STDIN and write to STDOUT in VB.NET please?

Comment: System.String is immutable, so it must never appear as a type for a buffer parameter.   Use StringBuilder instead.  And be sure to avoid the bug in this code that causes the AVE, you must set its Capacity before the call.

Comment: StringBuilder.......
I would appreciate a code sample please.
I'm an occasional .net programmer :-)

Comment: @RensDuijsens See [Default Marshaling for Strings: Fixed Length String Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#fixed-length-string-buffers). Though the example is written for C#, the same concept applies to VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering...

The .NET Framework provides a [`System.Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console) class, which contains functionality for reading/writing the standard input/output streams. Is there a special reason for not using that functionality?

I guess your `GetData` method could be rewritten to something like this:

```
Sub GetData()
    sFilterData = Console.In.ReadToEnd()
End Sub
```

However, it might be more efficient (especially for memory usage) to process the input stream data "on the fly" instead of reading and storing the entire input stream into a string first and then start processing.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you include using the `Console.IsInputRedirected` and `Console.IsOutputRedirected` to allow program flow control if not redirected.  Anyways good answer.

Comment: Well........sometimes things are simpeler the one would expect. :-)
Like I mentioned, my code came from VB6. 

I was not aware of the 'new' way to do this.
Yes, off cause this is much much better en simpeler.
Thanks for the heads up.
Thank you so much for the quick and clear answers.

Though I am wondering that is I try to find information on "VB.NET Read from STDIN" nothing like this comes up. I only see several variations of the Kernel32 way to do it.
Like for instance the way I read ini-files with "GetPrivateProfileString"

Comment: Ah yes. I see. When I personally try to search something on Google, I also try to search for potential documentation content, which often uses regular English terms. I just tried it by searching for "VB.NET read from standard input stream" and the first result is a reference to the `Console.OpenStandardInput` method. Perhaps STDIN was a too technical or too specific search criterium in your case... ;)

Comment: Support for INI files is not directly supported by the .NET Framework. You could indeed use kernel functions (`GetPrivateProfileString`) for that for now. However, in the long run (after migration of your app), I would advise to switch to an alternative file format for your configuration files, like XML or JSON. That would not only make your app more portable (when necessary), but it would also offer more technical configuration flexibility. (You might want to search for ".NET app.config" or ".NET Core appsettings.json" for more information about it.)

Comment: Thank you Bart, on both answers. Very useful.
A lot has changed since my VB6 days. :-D